# How to interpret Schoenfeld residual

Tags: cox-model, schoenfeld-residuals

[image: Schoenfeld residual]Hi all,

Could you please help me to interpret Schoenfeld residual below.
Of note, I have very few outcome in one arm (Only 6 events and around 60 in the other)